# Testimonials slider loop/query not working PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slick.js, testimonials

So, I am trying to display Testimonials with Slick slider but it is not working. I guess I linked the css and js files wrong or something because testimonials are displaying but slider doesn't work. So please help with troubleshooting.

This is code:

HTML

```
    <section class="reviews">
                <div class="row d-flex flex-column">
                    <div class="testimonial-holder">                
                        <?php
                            $args = array(
                            'post_type'   => 'testimonials',
                            // 'post_status' => 'publish',
                            // 'posts_per_page' => 1,
                            // 'order' => 'ASC',
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        ?>
                            <?php
                            while( $query->have_posts() ) :
                                $query->the_post(); 
                        ?>

                            <div class="lead-text d-flex text-center justify-content-center flex-column">
                                <?php echo '<p class="lead">' . get_the_content() . '</p>' . '<small>' . '-' . get_the_title() . '</small>'; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

ENQUE

```
function load_css() {

wp_register_style( 'slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/js/slick/slick.css', array(), false, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('slick');
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css' );

function load_js() {

```
wp_register_script( 'slick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/src/js/slick/slick.min.js', false, true);
wp_enqueue_script('slick');
```

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js' );

CALLING IT WITH JQUERY//This is only line of code and it should work

```
$('.testimonial-holder').slick();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach the .slick() callback on document.ready state?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure. I gave up on this, since I couldn't figure it out. Went with the plugin but even that is messing with me. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I pulled this off with Advanced Custom Fields with number field. I gave up on slider and changed the concept little bit. So, depends of the entered number in the filed, it will generate number of stars in the Front end.

```
<?php
                            $args = array(
                            'post_type'   => 'testimonials',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => 1,
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'orderby'=> 'rand',
                            );
                            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                                //if( $query->have_posts() ) :
                        ?>
                            <!-- Displaying testimonials -->
                    
                        <?php
                            while( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                                <!-- <div class="col-lg-4"> -->
                                <div class="content-holder">
                                    <?php $query->the_post(); ?>

                                    <div class="stars-holder">
                                        <?php 
                                            $star = get_field('stars');
                                            $count = 0;
                                            $element = '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
                                            while ($count < $star) : $count++;
                                                echo $element;
                                            endwhile;
                                        ?>  
                                    </div>                  
                                    <div class="lead-text d-flex text-center justify-content-center flex-column">
                                        <?php echo '<p class="lead">' . get_the_content() . '</p>' . '<small>' . '-' . get_the_title() . '</small>'; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!-- </div> -->
                            <?php endwhile;
                            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```